# Using PHP to convert email addresses to mailto with SEPARATE user/domain variables

Tags: php, regex

I have the below function based on an answer in SO that converts email addresses in a string to mailto links. However, I'm trying to take it one step further, and separate the username and domain name into separate variables. The below function instead separates everything before the last period into one variable and after the period into another.

```
function emailize($str)
{
    $mail_pattern = "/([A-z0-9\._-]+\@[A-z0-9_-]+\.)([A-z0-9\_\-\.]{1,}[A-z])/";
    $str = preg_replace($mail_pattern, '<a class='obfuscate' data-user="$1" data-domain="$2" href="#">Click Here</a>', $str);
    return $str;
}
```

Using test@example.com as the email address, I was hoping $1 would be `test` and $2 would be `example.com`.

Also, I will be passing a large string that potentially has multiple email addresses in it.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With altered capture groups you can achieve what you want. A `:?` in a capture group makes it non-capturing. So

```
([A-z0-9\._-]+)\@([A-z0-9_-]+\.(?:[A-z0-9\_\-\.]{1,}[A-z]))
```

should give you the username as 1 capture group and the domain as another.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/BF7p2g/1/